# Jetpack Compose Difference Between plain value and remember

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

If I have an immutable value which is used by multiple composables how should I
assign the value? Which option is more efficient. Does remember gives me performance gain ? This is a weird question but I couldn't find any example about it.

What I think: For option 1, on every recomposition, example value will be set over and over to 5.dp I think it's unnecessary because it's always 5.dp

For option 2, on first recomposition, example value will be set to 5.dp and will never be set again. I think using remember is more efficient but I am not sure.

```
    @Composable
    fun MyComposable() {
        val example = 5.dp //option 1
        val example = remember { 5.dp } //option 2

        Box(modifier = Modifier
           .height(example)
           .padding(example)) {

           Column {
               Text(text = "example", modifier = Modifier.padding(example))
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Does remember gives me performance gain ?

No.

`remember` should not be used as a performance optimization like this as the memoization it does is often redundant to what and `@Composable` function already does which is probably more than you were expecting.

Specifically, as `5.dp` is just a float value in disguise so Option 1 is more efficient.

You never need `remember` for primitives (or `value class` instances as in this case). This does nothing other than consume memory and time.

> ...on every recomposition, example value will be set over and over to 5.dp

This is not true. In this case, only initial composition will call `MyComposable` it will not be called again. This is because 1) it has no parameters so it will always skip, and 2) it doesn't observe any mutable state so it will never be restarted.

It will always skip because a composable function will skip whenever it is called with the same parameters as it was called with last time. That is, composable function are already memoized, you don't need to do this yourself.

A composable function will restart if it observes mutable state that has changed. The simplest example of this is reading the result of `mutableStateOf()` that has been assigned a new value. Compose will restart the composable functions that have read state that has changed to determine what the new composition should be that reflects the change.

If `MyComposable` was modified to have a parameter or it was modified to observed mutable state, it could be called during recomposition. Even then Compose tries to be smart here by checking if the modifier produces the same modifier it did last time. This allows `Box` and `Text` to skip, as none of their parameters changed. Well, `Box` doesn't skip as it is an inline function, but the call that is inlined does.

Compose memoizes the result of composition and will only execute the part of the composition that has changed. If the result of a function, like `MyComposable`, cannot change, it will only be called once. If it does get called but just calls composable functions with the same parameters, they will skip so the function will do very little.

Comment: "This is not true. In this case, only initial composition will call MyComposable it will not be called again" If MyComposable was a composable that recomposition frequently. Does it make difference ?  @chuckj

Comment: I tried to address that in my last paragraph. Even if this does get called a lot, Compose still tries to skip the functions that are called. It doesn't need `remember` to be called for this to happen. The parameter just need to be "stable" which means they are either immutable or observable. If you are calling Compose provided composables, they are very good about only surfacing parameters that are stable.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a val.  It's a constant.  Remember is used when a value can change and needs to be saved between compositions.